# Kendo Bind Visible to Opposite of Value

Tags: kendo-ui

I believe I already know the answer to this, but in kendo are you able to bind a DOM element's visibility to the opposite of if a value in the observable is null or false?

For example: the normal behavior is to show a `<div>` that has content the user needs to manipulate as part of a "step". I want to give the user the option to skip this step. To do this, I add a checkbox that says "skip" and in it I bind its value to the property IsSkip:

```
<input id="checkbox-allow-skip" type="checkbox" data-bind="value: IsSkip" />
```

Can I then bind the `<div>`'s visibility to the opposite of IsSkip like this (pseudo code for data-bind):

```
<div id="optional-step" data-bind="visible: !IsSkip">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Edit - I believe that it may be worth noting that currently I'm generating the `onchange` event of the checkbox and setting the value of a new property named *CannotSkip* to the opposite of IsSkip and binding the visibility to *CannotSkip*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're probably already aware, you can't invert the value of the property within your binding expression as per your pseudo code due to the way the binding is constructed. However, the `visible` reference which appears in the binding expression is not a reference to a DOM attribute, it's actually a reference to a kendo binder which has a counterpart, the `invisible` [binder](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/invisible) which inverts the value for you. Hence the simplest solution to your problem is just this:

```
<div id="optional-step" data-bind="invisible: IsSkip">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Eventually however, you're sure to encounter a situation where this won't solve the problem for you e.g. perhaps the visibility depends on the state of several flags? This type of scenario is best handled by binding to a function instead where you can execute whatever logic is necessary. The most important thing to remember when you use this approach is to manipulate any properties of your view-model using the `get` and `set` methods of the observable object. This ensures that any bindings to your function will be refreshed when any of those properties change; in kendo parlance this is known as a [dependent method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject#dependent-methods). You could solve your problem using this approach, like so:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  IsSkip: false,
  CannotSkip: function() {
    return !this.get("IsSkip");
  }
});

<div id="optional-step" data-bind="visible: CannotSkip">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, both suggestions were the most practical solution.